# What is the runtime representation of constraint-kinded type families?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

If I have a type family (closed or open, I'm interested in both)

```
type family F a :: Constraint
```

and a function with `F a` as a constraint, what does that function look like at runtime? What does the dictionary look like?

Motivation:
I'm trying to use the trick from `reflection` to discard an unneeded constraint from one of my functions and in some cases it works, in others I get a segfault so I'm looking for a more principled approach instead of my trial and error.

Edit:

Here's a code sample that does work

```
import Data.Kind
import Unsafe.Coerce

type family Elem (x :: k) (xs :: [k]) :: Bool where
    Elem x '[] = 'False
    Elem x (x ': xs) = 'True
    Elem x (y ': xs) = Elem x xs

type family IsSubset xs ys :: Constraint where
    IsSubset '[] ys = ()
    IsSubset (x ': xs) ys = (IsTrue (Elem x ys), IsSubset xs ys)

type IsTrue b = b ~ 'True

data Tagged l a = Tagged a deriving Show

g :: (Num a, IsSubset l1 l2) => Tagged l1 a -> Tagged l2 a -> Tagged l2 a
g (Tagged x) (Tagged y) = Tagged (x + y)

newtype Magic c a = Magic (c => a)

discard :: forall c a. (c => a) -> a
discard a = unsafeCoerce (Magic @c @a a) ()

f :: forall k l1 a. (Num a) => Tagged (l1 :: [k]) a -> Tagged l1 a -> Tagged l1 a
f = discard @(IsSubset l1 l1) g
```

and to test it:

```
> f (Tagged 1) (Tagged 2)
Tagged 3
```

Comment: It might be more useful if you can include a bit of the code you were playing around with (an example that worked, and one that segfaulted). I'm curious at least

Comment: @jberryman I'd love to, unfortunately, my minimal test case works, while the same implementation inside of a large project segfaults... I'm asking this question because I'm a bit tired digging through thousands of lines of core because of this very problem :D

Comment: Even the minimal test case could be useful. `Data.Reflection` turns off a few GHC optimizations; have you tried doing that?

Comment: @dfeuer I've added an example. Turning off the optimizations from Data.Reflection didn't fix my large project.

Comment: The constraints you've shown here just boil down to `~` constraints, which wouldn't have a need to actually have a dictionary passed at runtime. So it would make sense that a `c => a` would have the same runtime representation as an `a`, and your `unsafeCoerce` would be relatively safe. But if the constraint is a *class* constraint there could be methods, and I would *not* expect `c => a` to have the same representation as `a`. Could that be the difference between your working and failing example? Even if the class has no methods, I wonder if class constraints are just different from `~` ones.

Comment: @Ben The failing example is much too big to post here, but notice also that my code above demonstrates that `c => a` in fact is not the same as `a` because I do have to pass in a dummy parameter (`()` in this case). It seems the function still requires a dictionary, it just doesn't seem to use it.